# Selenium Timeout after 60 seconds when trying to create FirefoxDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

I am trying to create a simple Selenium Test Case using Firefox and C#. I have installed Selenium 3.8, Gecko 0.19 and have a portable copy of Firefox 54.0.1(64 bit).

When I try to run the following sample code, I get the error

> The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL
>   http://localhost:61397/session timed out after 60 seconds.

I get the same error no matter what I try. I have shared the code I have created below

```
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"D:\TestProject1\bin\Debug");
service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"D:\FirefoxPortable\FirefoxPortable.exe";
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);`
```

I get the error on executing the last line with timeout error. But, I do see a Firefox getting opened each time and cursor focused on the address bar each time

Answer (score 1):

For geckodriver 0.19 [Firefox 55 and greater is recommended](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.19.0). Upgrade the browser version.

Comment: thank you. Just realized that the Java needed to be updated. It is working now